# Vue update props on select options

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, vue-cli, optionmenu, vue-props

I'm using vue cli and I have a select to display a dropdown list of measurements. I’m wondering how I can update props when I select a measurement?

I have a user profile card that opens a modal with a chart displaying measurement for that user and when I'm in the modal I would like to select another measurement and display that instead.

So when I click on volume, the chart text changes to volume and displays volume data for that user.

I tried to do it for text of the chart via an event listener @change but the props are not passing down and changing the text:

```js
Select: <select name="show" class="show" v-model="value" @change="newText($event)">
                    <option :value="{ text: 'Volume'}">Vol</option>
                    <option :value="{ text: 'Weight'}">Weight</option>
                    <option :value="{ text: 'Temperature'}">Temp</option>
        </select> 

<script>
newText: function(event) {
        const text = this.value.text;
        this.text = text;
        },
<script>
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-chatelet-cjsbg?file=/src/components/Profile.vue) example.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the user object and render the value of that user. Here I find the clicked user using computed property inside the tab and render the value of that user. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-resonance-c2wvr?file=/src/components/Tabs.vue) .

**Computed** inside `Tabs.vue` :

```
computed: {
    selectedUser() {
      if (this.name) {
        let name = this.name;
        return this.users.find(e => e.name == name);
      } else return {}
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've updated my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lederberg-uxtet?file=/src/components/Tabs.vue with computed but it seems to not let me select user or change when I click on measurement, perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: use selectedUser as a vaule inside `Tabs.vue`.See my codesandbox

Comment: Thank you! I tried doing it but doesn't seem to work for me, I checked out the codesandbox but doesn't either seem to let me select a user. When I choose a different user it defaults back to the user whose profile card it is.